# Can I allow more than one app in "Single App Mode"?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, security

If I use "Apple Configurator 2" to lock an iOS device, can I allow two or three or four specific apps ?

Or is it really, literally, "single" app mode and only a single app can be allowed ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't allow more than one app in "Single App Mode"

[Apple also states](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-2/enable-single-app-mode-cadbf9c172/mac)

> Single App Mode forces the selected app to open on the supervised
>   device and prevents the use of other apps. When this payload is
>   active, the app reopens immediately after the device is restarted.